# How to define inline variable in Pug

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am using Pug template engine with Node + Express app.

I need some calculation in the Pug file. For example, I have an array of object and I have to print the sum of all object's amount field and need to show all amount in `table`.

for that, I am using `each` loop available in Pug.

I am trying like this :

```
   div
    each discount in el.Discounts
     if trxn.category != category
      var discountAmount = discount.amount * -1
      var distTotal = distTotal + discount.amount
      p= distTotal
```

But it is not working, I want to declare and update the inline variable.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: What is `p`? What is the output you are getting? What are you expecting? Please share some data.

Comment: P is HTML's paragraph tag. I am not getting any error but nor getting the result.

Comment: Shouldn't `p` be outside if statement? and also just define discountAmount and distTotal before each iterator as 0;

Answer (score 13):

In front of var you should write "-"

```
div
    each discount in el.Discounts
     if trxn.category != category
      - var discountAmount = discount.amount * -1
      - var distTotal = distTotal + discount.amount
      p= distTotal
```